# Cucumber Examples table using placeholder

Tags: go, cucumber, bdd

I am new to cucumber. I have cucumber scenario with Examples table as below:

```
  Scenario: TC-<ID> Negative - Reject - <TEST_CASE_DESCRIPTION>
    Given the profiles exists:
      | ID     | PRIMARY ID | MARKET   | FAMILY   |
      | <I_ID> | <P_ID>     | <MARKET> | <FAMILY> |
    Then the query request is not processed
      | HTTP RESPONSE CODE   | ERROR CODE   | DEVELOPER MESSAGE   | MORE INFORMATION   |
      | <HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE> | <ERROR_CODE> | <DEVELOPER_MESSAGE> | <MORE_INFORMATION> |

    Examples:
      | ID | TEST_CASE_DESCRIPTION                          | I_ID       | P_ID                | MARKET | FAMILY |  HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE | ERROR_CODE | DEVELOPER_MESSAGE                 | MORE_INFORMATION                                      |
      | 02 | Invalid "ID"                                   | I_<ID>     | 12765hgadjhs        | 156    | EE     |  404                | 007        | Error calling getAccount()        | error retrieving account for given id                 |
      | 03 | Invalid "P ID"                                 | I_<ID>     | P_<ID>              | 156    | EL     |  404                | 007        | Error calling getAccount()        | no active account for give p id                       |
      | 04 | Invalid "ID" and "PID" Combination             | I_<ID>     | P_<ID>              | 410    | HCC    |  404                | 007        | Error calling getAccount()        | no active account for given Id and p id combination   |
```

What I am trying to do is Test execution the values of ID will I_02, I_03, I_04 and Primary ID will be 12765hgadjhs , P_03 and P_04 respectively for each example execution.

Is there any way to go that?

Comment: Honestly, it wouldn't hurt readability to make four different scenarios. There is no need to reuse this aggressively.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but unfortunately it is just a part 60 odd scenarios.